# npm install does not work after installing choco for react native

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, react-native, gyp

I wanted to play around with react native cli so I installed this command "choco install -y nodejs.install python2 openjdk8" and I had to go back to other react project (different project) and needed to run "npm install". Now.. it returns this bunch of errors below.

> npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! path
> D:\ReactApp\GeoLocationApp\node_modules\node-sass npm ERR! command
> failed npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node
> scripts/build.js npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
> D:\ReactApp\GeoLocationApp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
> rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags=
> --libsass_library= npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok npm ERR! gyp verb cli [ npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node.exe', npm ERR! gyp verb cli
> 'D:\ReactApp\GeoLocationApp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js',
> npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild', npm ERR! gyp verb cli
> '--verbose', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=', npm ERR! gyp
> verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=', npm ERR! gyp verb cli
> '--libsass_ldflags=', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' npm
> ERR! gyp verb cli ] npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2 npm ERR!
> gyp info using node@16.0.0 | win32 | x64 npm ERR! gyp verb command
> rebuild [] npm ERR! gyp verb command clean [] npm ERR! gyp verb clean
> removing "build" directory npm ERR! gyp verb command configure [] npm
> ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm
> configuration npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from
> environment variable PYTHON npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if
> "python3" can be used npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing
> "python3" to get executable path npm ERR! gyp verb find Python -
> "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error npm ERR! gyp verb find
> Python checking if "python" can be used npm ERR! gyp verb find Python
>
> - executing "python" to get executable path npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error npm ERR! gyp
>   verb find Python checking if "python2" can be used npm ERR! gyp verb
>   find Python - executing "python2" to get executable path npm ERR! gyp
>   verb find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error npm
>   ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
>   npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Python37\python.exe" to
>   get version npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe"
>   could not be run npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if Python is
>   C:\Python27\python.exe npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing
>   "C:\Python27\python.exe" to get version npm ERR! gyp verb find Python
> - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python npm ERR!
>   gyp verb find Python - executing "py.exe" to get Python executable
>   path npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or
>   produced an error npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python npm ERR! gyp ERR! find
>   Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration npm
>   ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable
>   PYTHON npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
>   npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced
>   an error npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be
>   used npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or
>   produced an error npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2"
>   can be used npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH
>   or produced an error npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python
>   is C:\Python37\python.exe npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python -
>   "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run npm ERR! gyp ERR! find
>   Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe npm ERR! gyp ERR!
>   find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run npm ERR! gyp
>   ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find
>   Python npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or
>   produced an error npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python npm ERR! gyp ERR! find
>   Python ********************************************************** npm
>   ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of
>   Python. npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find
>   and use Python. If not, npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one
>   of the following options: npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the
>   switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe" npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
>   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm) npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python -
>   Set the environment variable PYTHON npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python -
>   Set the npm configuration variable python: npm ERR! gyp ERR! find
>   Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe" npm ERR! gyp
>   ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
>   npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
>   https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation npm ERR! gyp ERR! find
>   Python ********************************************************** npm
>   ERR! gyp ERR! find Python npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error npm ERR!
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
>   npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail
>   (D:\ReactApp\GeoLocationApp\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:302:47)
>   npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks
>   (D:\ReactApp\GeoLocationApp\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
>   npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback
>   (D:\ReactApp\GeoLocationApp\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:266:16)
>   npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:333:5)
>   npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler
>   (node:child_process:345:5) npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28) npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (node:internal/child_process:288:12) npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at
>   onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16) npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
>   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
>   npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042 npm ERR! gyp ERR!
>   command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "D:\ReactApp\GeoLocationApp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags="
>   "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library=" npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd
>   D:\ReactApp\GeoLocationApp\node_modules\node-sass npm ERR! gyp ERR!
>   node -v v16.0.0 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2 npm ERR! gyp ERR!
>   not ok npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users***\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-04-26T22_35_37_763Z-debug.log
> PS D:\ReactApp\GeoLocationApp> npm install --global --production
> windows-build-tools npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this
> library is no longer supported npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2:
> request has been deprecated, see
> https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 npm ERR! code 1 npm
> ERR! path
> C:\Users****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools npm
> ERR! command failed npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s
> /c node ./dist/index.js Downloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi npm ERR!
> [>                                            ] 0.0% (0 B/s) npm ERR!
> Downloaded python-2.7.15.amd64.msi. Saved to
> C:\Users***.windows-build-tools\python-2.7.15.amd64.msi. Downloading
> vs_BuildTools.exe npm ERR! [>
>
> ] 0.0% (0 B/s) npm ERR! Downloaded vs_BuildTools.exe. Saved to
> C:\Users***.windows-build-tools\vs_BuildTools.exe. npm ERR! npm ERR!
> Starting installation... npm ERR! Please restart this script from an
> administrative PowerShell! npm ERR! The build tools cannot be
> installed without administrative rights. npm ERR! To fix, right-click
> on PowerShell and run "as Administrator".
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users***\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-04-26T22_37_32_622Z-debug.log

I tried running "install --global windows-build-tools" and also tried to run this command as well "npm install node-gyp" but it does not fix the issue... (run as admin at windows powershell,cmd, and git bash).

Also, I downloaded the python27 and installed at this path "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python".

After that I added the env variable with this two path below
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\Scripts
and still does not work..

Also I tried deleting whole vs code and redownload the vscode but that didn't work as well.

I even deleted package-lock.json and node module but that did not work..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try npm i axios or something like that. Does that work? If not, try running sudo first. If it still doesn't work, you may have messed up your system. I would try installing nodejs from the web link and python from the weblink too. If you cannot install it graphically, maybe try resetting your entire computer and installing node and python graphically.

Don't use the terminal to install node or python IMO, it is better to go to their website and do it through the link and run the installer on your computer.

Comment: hello thank you for your response. nope... even axios does not install... when you said reset the entire computer is that mean reset to factory setting? I even tried adding the python env varible too... but that does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Okay... So I figured it out.. What I did is just uninstalled the node js and reinstalled node js and that fixed the problem. Not sure if this is the best way to fix it but it worked!!